# Is there a way i can recover my deleted .env laravel file from server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, server, configuration

I am using the laravel 5.6. I did some configurations in the server and somehow .env file is corrupted. Can i recover this with the same configurations

Comment: If you have a backup then yes, otherwise no.

Comment: Talk to your server administrator, but most likely not.

Comment: You should have an `.env.example` file with the same structure as your actual `.env`; just fill in the values with the correct information.  The only thing that will have an issue is database records dependant on the `APP_KEY` (generally `password` hash fields). You'll likely have to instruct users to do a password reset, re-encrypt any encrypted data, etc.

Comment: @TimLewis actually .env.example have old configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. you cant recover the environment file.

however you can use some data-recovery tools and try your luck,